# Printing an std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

So, while playing around with std::array, I wanted an easy way to print out all elements of an array, and tried the following:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const array<T, N>& arr)
{
    copy(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), ostream_iterator<T>(o, " "));
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    array<int, 3> arr {1, 2, 3};
    cout << arr;
}
```

However, whenever I try to run this, I get the following errors:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:21:10: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/ostream:581:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = std::array<int, 3u>]'
```

Any ideas on what this error means, and how I would go about fixing it?

If I replace operator<< with a function like template<...> print_array(const array&), the error changes:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:20:17: error: no matching function for call to 'print_array(std::array<int, 3u>&)'
test.cpp:20:17: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:12:6: note: template<class T, int N> void print_array(const std::array<T, N>&)
```

Comment: Which compiler is it? Because your code compiles and runs on Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: std::array is `<T,size_t>` not `<T,int>`. May be your compiler don't find the match. can you upgrade to 4.7 or even 4.8? 4.6 was not fully C++11 compliant.

Comment: Works on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9JzUr9), although I did have to change `int` to `size_t`.

Comment: It worked on vc12 for me, and only broke when I tried using gcc (4.6.2). Changing it to size_t fixed it though, thanks!

Comment: I also recently had a problem with printing that was like this one, down to the `basic_ostream&&` conflict.  The I/O stream operator overloads use an l-value reference to a stream.  To cover r-value streams, there is a universal `operator <<` that just converts the stream to an l-value reference before doing regular streaming.  Any normal mismatch in streaming will not report a direct no-overload match, since the universal r-value overload will (attempt to) match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `std::size_t` to help compiler to deduce types:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const array<T, N>& arr)
{
    copy(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), ostream_iterator<T>(o, " "));
    return o;
}
```